# how to maintain an ordered list using a rank column? (sql)

Tags: sql

Consider a table with the following columns:

```
ID, Name, Rank
```

And data like:

```
100, John, 1
200, Steve, 2
300, Mike, 3
400, Ben, 4
500, Jake, 5
```

The Rank is unique.

What's the best way of updating the table if I want to give Ben a rank of 2 and update the rest accordingly so that I would end up with

```
100, John, 1
400, Ben, 2
200, Steve, 3
300, Mike, 4
500, Jake, 5
```

Is there a smarter way to do this than changing Ben's rank to 2 and updating every row between his new and old rank?

Comment: on which basis you are deciding rank

Comment: It looks like it's just another field.

Comment: Is there a 'Unique' INDEX constraint on Rank?

Comment: yes, at least that's how I thought it should be, unique, because there shouldn't be two rows with same rank. And yes, it's just another column.

Answer (score 2):

As there has been some back and forth, this is how I would do this (using SQL Server notation):

```
SELECT @CurrentRank = Rank FROM TableName WHERE Id = @SelectedId

UPDATE TableName
SET Rank= 
CASE
    WHEN Id = @SelectedId THEN @NewSelectedRank
    WHEN @NewSelectedRank < @CurrentRank 
        AND Rank >= @NewSelectedRank AND Rank < @CurrentRank
    THEN Rank = Rank + 1
    WHEN @NewSelectedRank > @CurrentRank 
        AND Rank <= @NewSelectedRank AND Rank > @CurrentRank
    THEN Rank = Rank - 1
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method.  This will avoid the duplicate key issue (assuming you have an Unique constraint on Rank).  Updated to work if rank is less than current rank.

```
DECLARE @ID int, @NewRank int, @CurrentRank int, @LowRank int, @HighRank int
SET @ID=400
SET @NEWRANK=2

SELECT @CurrentRank = Rank FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @ID
SET @LowRank = CASE WHEN @NewRank < @CurrentRank THEN @NewRank ELSE @CurrentRank END
SET @HighRank = CASE WHEN @NewRank < @CurrentRank THEN @CurrentRank ELSE @NewRank END

UPDATE MyTable SET Rank = -Rank WHERE Rank BETWEEN @LowRank AND @HighRank

UPDATE MyTable SET Rank = @NewRank WHERE ID = @ID

UPDATE MyTable SET Rank = 
    CASE 
    WHEN @NewRank < @CurrentRank THEN  -Rank + 1
    ELSE -Rank - 1
    END
WHERE Rank < 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Are yoru ranks able to be computed dynamically based on some other columns you can order by?  If so, then you may be able to use the ROW_NUMBER function in some RDBMS's to calculate and update your ranks accordingly.

If not, another method (kind of a cheat) would be to use decimals for your rank, and assign Ben a value of 1.5 :)  This is assuming that you're not displaying the rank directly from your database.

Comment: Nope, they are "just ranks" that user can assign to the rows (think of an UI where you could drag and drop list items to "rank" them) - I'm not sure if I understood the point of having a decimal rank.

Comment: The decimal rank would allow you to update one row in between two other rows without touching any other row.  For example, if you know that Ben goes between John and Steve, and you know that Steve has a value of 2, and John has a value of 1, assigning Ben a value of 1.5 keeps you from having to update anybody else.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be unnecessarily fancy about it (or have other reasons to do it this way,) and you can plan on just updating the rank of the single row being moved with a single update query, you can use a trigger to force the other rows to update. This would be done as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_RankChange]
  ON [dbo].[table_name]  Before UPDATE AS 
  BEGIN 
    Update [dbo].[table_name] Set Rank = Rank + 1 Where rank >= New.Rank
    Update [dbo].[table_name] Set Rank = Rank - 1 Where rank >= Old.Rank
  END
```

I basically wanted to point out that it can be done thing way, not recommend doing it. It is not recommended if you're not familiar with all the other logic that wil lbe applied to the table; if this will be a large scale project with other things going on, you may want to be very careful due to the possible complexity of triggers.

Comment: ok, thanks, given my weak SQL skills, I think I will stick to simpler solutions

Comment: Good; I wanted to make sure that this idea was presented, so that people who saw the question knew that it was an option, but that it had drawbacks.